# I keep getting UnicodeDecodeError even after changing encoding types

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

I did import sys and checked that the default encoding was already utf-8.
This is my function, from top to bottom is what I try to open with and the errors I got.

```
def get_file_data(self, filename, connection_string = "", readlines=False):
    file_data = None
    tmp_file_path = copyfile.make_temp_path()
    try:
        if connection_string:
            source_file = copyfile.join(connection_string, filename)
        else:
            source_file = filename
    copyfile.copyfile(source_file, tmp_file_path)

    tmp_file = open(tmp_file_path, "r") # gives error ('ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 10: ordinal not in range(128))
    tmp_file = open(tmp_file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") # gives error ('utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 10: invalid start byte)
    tmp_file = open(tmp_file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-16") # gives error ('utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 156: truncated data)

    if readlines:
        file_data = tmp_file.readlines()
    else:
        file_data = tmp_file.read()

    
    tmp_file.close()
finally:
    os.remove(tmp_file_path)

return file_data

Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "./leds/bin/tx_crash_accident_import.py", line 56, in task
            zip_file = self.get_remote_file_data(zip_filename, connection_str)
          File "/leds/leds/python/interfaces/interfaces_import/interfaces_import.py", line 1837, in get_remote_file_data
            file_data = tmp_file.read()
          File "/opt/leds_py3/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
            return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 13:43:44    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
        None
warn:   13:43:44    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "./leds/bin/tx_crash_accident_import.py", line 56, in task
            zip_file = self.get_remote_file_data(zip_filename, connection_str)
          File "/leds/leds/python/interfaces/interfaces_import/interfaces_import.py", line 1837, in get_remote_file_data
            file_data = tmp_file.read()
          File "/opt/leds_py3/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
            return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 13:43:44    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What else can I try here? I read something about changing the system locales, but that would be my last resort.

Comment: `U+009A` is (control) *Single Character Introducer*. However, `\x9a` is a valid (non-control) character in following encodings (space separated): `cp037 cp437 cp720 cp737 cp855 cp856 cp864 cp866 cp869 cp875 cp1250 cp1251 cp1256 koi8_r ptcp154 mac_roman`. Are you sure that you have a **plain text file**?

Comment: so the file itself is a 7zip file, for this example I used a simple .txt file with english characters "asdf" and zipped it. Which is part of a different function that calls to this one.

Comment: If the file is zipped, it isn't UTF-8 anymore. You'll need to uncompress it first.

Comment: Could it be because my system locale is giving me a different encoding? If I do >> import locale >>locale.getpreferredencoding(False) it's giving me 'ANSI_X3.4-1968', but in Pycharm if I import sys, print(sys.getdefaultencoding()) it's giving me utf-8

Comment: The encoding doesn't matter if this is a zip file. You must first decompress it. Then you can apply string encodings. There is no string encoding that is appropriate for reading a compressed file.